# Why is this a string and not an integer? Two lines of code seem similar but behave differently

Tags: python, json

I'm pulling the data for this code from the wunderground API and one line:

```
sunsethour = parsed_json ['moon_phase']['sunset']['hour']
sunsetminute = parsed_json ['moon_phase']['sunset']['minute']
print "\nSunset is at: %s:%s" % (sunsethour, sunsetminute)
hightide = parsed_json ['tide']['tideSummary']['date']
print (hightide)
f.close()
```

While the sunset time prints fine, the hightide time produces the error "list indices must be integers, not str"

Very new to python and just trying to find my way. Please go easy on me, some dialog around here seems pretty intimidating.

**EDIT** here is the json: http://api.wunderground.com/api/a66b1087ab1e51a5/geolookup/conditions/astronomy/tide/q/MA/Boston.json

Truncated example:

```
{
  "tide": {
    "tideInfo": [
      {
        "tideSite": "Chelsea St. Bridge, Chelsea River, ...", 
        "lon": "-71.0233", 
        "units": "feet", 
        "tzname": "America/New_York", 
        "lat": "42.3867", 
        "type": "tide"
      }
    ], 
    "tideSummaryStats": [
      {
        "minheight": 99.0, 
        "maxheight": -99.0
      }
    ], 
    "tideSummary": []
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, what's the value of `parsed_json['tide']['tideSummary']` or `parsed_json['tide']`? We cannot help you if we don't know what data you are working with. The error message is pretty clear though: Either `parsed_json['tide']` or `parsed_json['tide']['tideSummary']` is a **list** and not a dictionary as you think. Have a look at the data and use the appropriate method to access it.

Comment: Please show the full stack trace. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Please post the JSON being parsed.

Comment: Presumably this means that the `parsed_json` dict entry for `tide` or `tideSummary` is not a dict (and cannot therefore be accessed with a string).

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the source JSON, here is the best that I can give so far:

```
hightide = parsed_json ['tide']['tideSummary']['date']
```

This assumes that the root element, and two child elements are all dictionaries, which can be accessed via string keys. Apparently one of these data elements is a list and not a dictionary:

```
parsed_json['tide']  # could be a list of tides?
parsed_json['tide']['tideSummary'] # could be a list of tide summaries?
parsed_json['tide']['tideSummary']['date'] # could be a list of dates?
```

All of those must produce dictionaries. Look at the values and see if any of them are actually lists:

```
aList = ['1','2','3']
aDict = {'1':1, '2':2, '3':3}

>>> aList['1']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

>>> aDict['1']
1
```

**Update**

From your update of the json structure, it is `parsed_json ['tide']['tideSummary']` that is causing you problems. The value of `tideSummary` is a list, though your data has it empty so I am not sure what is inside.

If it were a list of summary dicts that had date values, then you might do:

```
# assume:  parsed_json['tide']['tideSummary'] = [{"date":"value"}]

for summary in parsed_json['tide']['tideSummary']:
    print summary['date']
```

... Again, this assume they are a list of `{"date":"value"}`

Comment: thank you so much for all of the help. it appears as though part of the issue is related to the data not always appearing in the json. hence why @jdi found tideSummary empty. It's been on and off for me since I first posted. May be time to look elsewhere for my data.

Comment: @user1550220: Well yea it would be good if the data source is reliable. But as long as you are checking for it to be a list, regardless of whether it is empty or not, it should not crash like that anymore.